# Extract C functions' parameter types

Tags: c, linux, parameters, llvm

Given a .c file and a function name that identifies a function defined in the file, how can we automatically extract the types (in its verbatim string form) of its parameters? For example, the C function looks like

```
int foo(double x, double* y){...}
```

I need to output to a file, say `types`, with two lines

```
double 
double*
```

I guess LLVM should be an overkill. Maybe using a simple Unix command, such as'awk' can already do the job?

Comment: If you want it working, go with a real parser like the one you get from libclang.

Comment: _automatically_?  Are you talking about file parsing via command line, or programmatic parsing?  `awk` is great in a unix environment for either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ctags -x xpd.c | sed -n '/function/{s/.*(//; s/).*//; /^$/d;
s/\*\([^ ]\)/* \1/; s/ *[^ ]*, */\n/g; s/ *[^ ]*$//; p; }'
```

This pulls the types out of my C code, but I can't say that it will work for all C - YMMV.

Some notes on the sed:

- the first three statements yield a buffer like so: `double x, double *y`
- the next statement separates `*y` into `* y`
- the next turns an identifier followed by a comma into a newline: `x, -> \n`
- the last replacement throws away the trailing identifier: `y`

Comment: Wow. This is impresisve!